# Include Vue.js component in Wordpress plugin without CDN

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2

I am a bit used to develop Vue.js Single page application using Vue-cli. This time, I want something a different: develop a component with Vue.js (data visualisation on a map) and include it in Wordpress.

I found this tutorial on how to do that : https://deliciousbrains.com/vue-2-wordpress-plugin-tutorial/ and it seems pretty spot on. But it uses Vue.js via a CDN.

Are there technical solutions to do the same thing without using a CDN ? In a more generic manner, what are the technical solutions to include a modular Vue.js component into a Wordpress plugin ?

Comment: You can just download the vue.js file and include it in your plugin files, but you'd have to update it every time there's a new version. Why don't you want to use a CDN?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, because we already have a SPA in Vue.js for the backoffice and we want to develop components that can both be used in the public frontend and the backoffice without having to copy-paste code (in short, have a very modular approach). Also CDN availability depends on a third party server, and we are not very keen about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vue-cli as you're used to, and then simply call your build.js file in wordpress instead of CDN, using the wordpress function:

```
wp_enqueue_script()
```

Comment: I include `dist/bundle.js` file using `wp_enqueue_script()`. `main.js` (webpack entry point) works fine. Vue component mounted hook run, but the `template` tag wouldn't be compiled. I appreciate it if you could help me out.