# How to build a Vue.js project to use it in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

Update : see edit at the end

Follow up of my previous question here : [Include Vue.js component in Wordpress plugin without CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634124/include-vue-js-component-in-wordpress-plugin-without-cdn/53634303#53634303)

The very pertinent answer from Okba is causing me headaches. How do I build something with Vue.js that I can use in wordpress ?

I work with Vue-cli. I have tried to build my project as a library using this command line :

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myVueLibrary ./src/main.js
```

And then importing the `dist/*` files in wordpress :

```
wp_enqueue_script('myPlugin', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . './my-plugin.js', [], '0.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('myVueLibrary', './vue-plugin/myVueLibrary.common.js', [], '0.1.0');
```

where `my-plugin.js` looks like this (I am using shortcodes to replace a `<div>` content with whatever my plugin puts there) :

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[my-plugin-atts]');

elements.forEach(function (element) {
    var atts = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('my-plugin-atts'));
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: element,
        created: function () {
            this.atts = atts;
        },
        template: '<div class="plugin-container">{{atts.id}}</div>'
    });
});
```

And I get the following error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

But ! If I replace my `vueBaoViz.common.js` import by a Vue CDN import, my wordpress plugin displays what I want it to display.

```
wp_enqueue_script('myPlugin', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . './my-plugin.js', [], '0.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('vue', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js', [], '2.5.16');
```

My guess is my Vue build is not ok, how do I build something I can use like that, and that packs Vue.js within itself ?

Comment: You also can try using this Wordpress Vue Theme starter: https://github.com/EvanAgee/vuejs-wordpress-theme-starter

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can use vue js - non spa, from cdn or with webpack look at the https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Composing-with-Components for how you will use vue js in regular js files.

2- You can use vue-cli like a standart spa project with wordpress rest api : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: importing the vue.js production file (dowloaded directly from their website) as per the installation instruction does not work, and I don't want to use the CDN version. Using the Wordpress rest API seems overkill for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out i'm an idiot, I forgot to add `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)` before the path when loading a local file. This solved my problem.